# upload file with nodejs and connect-form

Tags: forms, node.js, file-upload, express

I've followed the [express multipart example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/multipart/app.js) to upload a file to server, and it works fine. But if I use a route middleware like this (coffeescript):

```
loadUser = (req, res, next) ->
    if req.session.user_id?
        db.user.findById req.session.user_id, (err, user) ->
            if user?
                req.currentUser = user
                next()
            else
                next()
    else
        next()

app.post '/file',loadUser, (req, res) ->
    req.form.complete (err, fields, files) ->
        if (err)
            console.error err
        else
            console.log '\nuploaded %s to %s', files.image.filename, files.image.path
    req.form.on 'progress', (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) ->
        percent = (bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100) | 0;
        process.stdout.write 'Uploading: %' + percent + '\r'
```

The file doesn't upload and there's nothing log and no error.
Then I clear the code in loadUser like this:

```
loadUser = (req, res, next) ->
    next()
```

It works fine again.
Is there something wrong in my loadUser method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem, because when the program route to the '/file', the form.complete had been emitted in the loadUser middleware. So there's nothing log and no error.